# Yeoman webapp generator - How to run mocha tests in the Browser

Tags: testing, gruntjs, mocha.js, yeoman, chai

I've got some JS tests written in mocha/chai and I would like to run them in a project scaffolded using the webapp generator.

I've put my tests inside the "test" folder from Yeoman's structure and the tests are running fine. But the issue is that the `grunt test` command is only showing the test results in the console, not in the browser.

I'm looking for a way to run the command and have the tests shown in the browser. How can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this part of `connect`'s configuration (more precisely, this is a sub-task of `connect`):

```
test    : {
  options : {
    middleware : function(connect) {
      return [
        require('connect-livereload')(),
        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
        mountFolder(connect, 'test')
      ];
    },
    port       : grunt.option('port') ? Number(grunt.option('port')) + 1 : 9001
  }
}
```

The above will make files from the specified folders available through http.

- `.tmp` is where my transpiled coffeescript and SCSS is landing as regular JS/CSS
- `test` is where my tests reside together with a very simple `index.html` file which wires all JS/CSS together, including `mocha.js` and `mocha.css`

Later in my Gruntfile I register the `test` task:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
  var tasks = [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee',
    'jst',
    'connect:test'
  ];

  if (target === 'browser') {
    tasks.push('open:test');
    tasks.push('watch');
  } else {
    tasks.push('mocha');
  }

  grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

The part which is relevant to your problem is `'connect:test'` which makes it possible to access the tests through the browser, and this one:

```
  if (target === 'browser') {
    tasks.push('open:test');
    tasks.push('watch');
  } else {
    tasks.push('mocha');
  }
```

As long as you don't specify `browser` as your `test` target, the tests will run headlessly in the console. But if you go like `grunt test:browser`, Grunt will open a browser thanks to `open:test`. For your reference, I also include my `open:test` config:

```
test   : {
  path : 'http://localhost:<%= connect.test.options.port %>'
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  I'll try this out ASAP.